# Android Phone Call Intent

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, phone-call

I am trying to make a call with the help of button, compiling time shows no errors but the application stops working as soon as i start the app, both on emulator and my android device. i have also set the permissions in the manifest file. but still :\
please help

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makeCall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/make_call" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.phonecalldemo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makeCall);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makeCall();
            }
        });
    }
    protected void makeCall() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");
        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:8866158630"));
        startActivity(phoneIntent);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.phonecalldemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.phonecalldemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what the error you have?

Comment: Please post the stack trace or any sort of logging information that was in logcat.

Comment: remove <permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></permission>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't instantiate abstract classes. Remove the 'abstract' from "public abstract class MainActivity", which will give you a different error telling you to implement the onClick method. Once you add that method that your app will launch.